# Cabling for SAS controller and SuperMicro BPN-SAS-825TQ

Tags: hp-smart-array, supermicro, cable

I´ve managed to get one of the SuperMicro low-end server to my lab. It is chassis 825TQ-R740LPB with a BPN-SAS-825TQ backplane. The specification document is saying, that this backplane is SAS compatible. But the server has a motherboard with only a SATA controller. All 8 SATA ports from the motherboard are connected to the backplane´s SATA ports.

Now, I want to use SAS disks in that enclosure. I have a spare HP P410 Smart Array card, so I am thinking about using it. What is not so clear to me is the connection from the controller to the backplane. Normally in HP backplanes, there are miniSAS ports, so I am using cables like this one ([https://www.amazon.com/HP-579265-001-Mini-SFF-8087-Cable/dp/B00H7B34EY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H7B34EY)) to conenct the backplane with the controller. But on the BPN-SAS-825TQ, there are only SATA ports. Do I understand correctly, that if I use this cable https://store.supermicro.com/supermicro-internal-minisas-to-4-sata-50-50-50-50cm-with-sideband-50cm-cable-cbl-0097l-02.html (actually two of them) together with the P410 RAID controller, it will be possible to use SAS disks in that enclosure?

Answer (score 1):

HP P410 has mini-SAS (SFF-8087) connectors, so you can use Supermicro CBL-0097L-02 or CBL-0176L-02, or any other SFF-8087->4x SATA cable except crossover ones.

Comment: Seconding that - if the backplane has SATA connectors you need a SFF-8087-to-4xSATA fanout cable (or two), regardless of whether you run SAS or SATA over that cable. There are even SAS RAID controllers (and possibly HBAs) with all SATA connectors.